# Adding integers to an array list, preserving order of input

Tags: java, arraylist, static

How do I add numbers to an ArrayList, but maintain the order that they were added?

Ex) Arraylist contains: [5, 3, 9]...I want to add [1, 2, 3] to make the modified list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 9]

Ex2) Arraylist contains: []...I want to add [1, 2, 3] to make the modified list = [1, 2, 3]

I'll be using one static arraylist the entire time

The user will be inputting the command from the command line by inputting: "a X1 X2 X3...Xn" where 'a' is the command and X1 - Xn are an unknown amount of integers to be added to the list

Comment: Are you trying to sort it? or just adding stuff to the beginning?

Comment: Preserving the order they were added would mean that the new items would go on the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question completely, but have you tried using simply:

```
arrayList.addAll(0, newDataUserProvided);
```

It should do the trick - the new elements will be always added at the front of the list.

Answer (score 0):

For `ArrayList<T>`, the method `void add(int index, T e)` actually inserts the element `e` at index `index`.
The index has to be between [0, length]
In order to achieve what you want, just do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList; // contains [5, 3, 9]
myList.add(0, 1);
myList.add(1, 2);
myList.add(2, 3);
// myList is now [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 9]
```

A `List` is an ordered collection, it means it keeps a specific order for the elements. For `ArrayList` the `void add(T e)` method, add an element at the end of the list, `void add(int index, T e)` insert an element at a specified position.

For your problem, you may only need to add element to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

List interface ans aller implémentations are used to manage elements by position and not by sorting. my list.get(3)

But if you want to have a structured list that implements sorting you have tow solutions :

1. Use a sortedSet, this set sort the given elements by natural sorting (compare method) that is implemented with integer values.
2. Use the collection.sort() to sort your final list (this solution is bad when you have a big list because it will case a performance problems)

   List myList = new ArrayList();
   myList.add(2); 
   myList.add(1);
   myList.add(3);
   Collections.sort(myList); 
   for (Integer i : strings){ System.out.println(i); 
   } // Prints out 1,2 and 3
3. Write your own SortedList

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have ordered collection that may contain duplicate. You should use `List`.
There are two implements for that

1. `ArrayList`
2. `LinkedList`

If you want to ordered collection based on insertions that may not contain duplicate. You should use one of implements of `Set` which is `LinkedHashSet`.
There are one implements

In `Java 8` , you can use `flatMap` to create a stream from the stream of lists

[image]

Code:

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
    List<Integer> finalList = Stream.of(list1 , list2)
                                    .flatMap( listF -> listF.stream())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(finalList);
```

Ouput:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```